# Php empty result

Tags: php, mysql

The result I get in the query I run with Mysql is the result I want. But when I send the same values ​​in my php code (even though the query is the same), it returns null.The query is a bit long but I thought I could do it. Trying a few things to improve myself

```
SELECT user_pictures.picture,users.username,
                    star,quest1.answer1,quest2.answer2,
                    quest3.answer3,quest4.answer4,quest5.answer5,
                    votes.created_at 
            FROM votes 
                LEFT JOIN user_pictures ON votes.voted_image_id=user_pictures.ID 
                LEFT JOIN users ON votes.voting_id=users.ID 
                LEFT JOIN quest1 ON votes.q1=quest1.ID 
                LEFT JOIN quest2 ON votes.q2=quest2.ID 
                LEFT JOIN quest3 ON votes.q3=quest3.ID 
                LEFT JOIN quest4 ON votes.q4=quest4.ID 
                LEFT JOIN quest5 ON votes.q5=quest5.ID 
            WHERE voted_id = "123456" 
            AND voting_id = "123"
```

[image]

how can i get the same result in my php code

```
<?php
require_once('connection.php');

if($_GET){
    $voted_id = $_GET['voted_id'];
    $voting_id = $_GET['voting_id'];

    $sql = "SELECT user_pictures.picture,users.username,
                    star,quest1.answer1,quest2.answer2,
                    quest3.answer3,quest4.answer4,quest5.answer5,
                    votes.created_at 
            FROM votes 
                LEFT JOIN user_pictures ON votes.voted_image_id=user_pictures.ID 
                LEFT JOIN users ON votes.voting_id=users.ID 
                LEFT JOIN quest1 ON votes.q1=quest1.ID 
                LEFT JOIN quest2 ON votes.q2=quest2.ID 
                LEFT JOIN quest3 ON votes.q3=quest3.ID 
                LEFT JOIN quest4 ON votes.q4=quest4.ID 
                LEFT JOIN quest5 ON votes.q5=quest5.ID 
            WHERE voted_id = ? 
            AND voting_id = ? ";
    $stmt = $connect->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bind_param("ii", $voted_id, $voting_id);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    $data = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);   
    
    header('Content-Type:application/json;charset=urf-8');
    echo json_encode($data);
}
?>
```

When I use var_dump($data) and var_dump($_GET) I can get the result I got in sql

```
array(2) {
    [
        "voting_id"
    ]=>
  string(6) "123456"
  [
        "voted_id"
    ]=>
  string(3) "123"
}
array(2) {
    [
        0
    ]=>
  array(9) {
        [
            "picture"
        ]=>
    string(4) "pic2"
    [
            "username"
        ]=>
    string(18) "Cihangir Karabulut"
    [
            "star"
        ]=>
    string(1) "2"
    [
            "answer1"
        ]=>
    string(6) "Patron"
    [
            "answer2"
        ]=>
    string(5) "?tici"
    [
            "answer3"
        ]=>
    string(4) "Sexy"
    [
            "answer4"
        ]=>
    string(9) "Karadeniz"
    [
            "answer5"
        ]=>
    string(5) "50-59"
    [
            "created_at"
        ]=>
    string(19) "2023-01-24 14:16:24"
    }
  [
        1
    ]=>
  array(9) {
        [
            "picture"
        ]=>
    string(4) "pic2"
    [
            "username"
        ]=>
    string(18) "Cihangir Karabulut"
    [
            "star"
        ]=>
    string(1) "4"
    [
            "answer1"
        ]=>
    string(7) "�?renci"
    [
            "answer2"
        ]=>
    string(9) "G�venilir"
    [
            "answer3"
        ]=>
    string(10) "At H?rs?z?"
    [
            "answer4"
        ]=>
    string(6) "Do?ulu"
    [
            "answer5"
        ]=>
    string(5) "25-29"
    [
            "created_at"
        ]=>
    string(19) "2023-01-24 19:20:28"
    }
}
```

Comment: Good code indentation would help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: As per [ask] please don't include pictures of code or data. There's no reason that SQL can't be provided as usable text. You can [edit] your post. Thanks

Comment: @ADyson The SQL is in the code block.

Comment: And its even readable now, If you can see it then maybe you can debug it

Comment: What debugging have you done? Use `var_dump($_GET);` to check the input values contain exactly what you expected. And `var_dump($data);` to see what rows the query returns (in case there was a problem in the JSON encoding process).

Comment: Are you sure the `if` condition is true and the query is being executed?

Comment: thank you to the people who helped me this is my first question i will take what you said into consideration

Comment: @Barmar that's the PHP-embedded version. I'm talking about the version they evidently ran in their SQL editor, with hard-coded values instead of ?s. Just in case they're otherwise different somehow. Much easier to analyse if they're both text.

Comment: if condition works, when I try with another sql query, I can get results

Comment: I don't think there is a problem in my php code because when I write another query, I can get results, but this query returns a null value.

Comment: Ok. So debug it as I suggested, then.

Comment: I saw the results I wanted when I used var_dump() .

Comment: I still don't understand how to return it as json

Comment: Hmm. Including the dump of $data? It contains all the rows, you mean? It would be better to edit your question and actually show us the outputs, rather than just asserting that you're happy with it

Comment: I added the result I got to my question. result returns same values ​​as sql output

Comment: Thanks. Have you tried using [json_last_error_msg()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error-msg.php) to see if something goes wrong in the encoding process?

Comment: Also, looks like you may have some interesting characters in the data. Have you tried using the  `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE` or `JSON_INVALID_UTF8_IGNORE` flag when encoding? See https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php and https://www.php.net/manual/en/json.constants.php

Comment: json_last_error_msg();   when i use it i get no error result

Comment: thank you for your answer i think i was getting this error because of the strange letters when i fixed it i got the answer i wanted

Comment: Personally I didn't downvote. But the first two or 3 comments probably explain why people downvoted - badly-presented code, and lack of obvious debugging effort leading to a less-than-clear scenario. If you fix it, they might retract the votes.

Comment: I understood my mistake and corrected it, I hope I understood correctly